Blender 4.2: Activate extension with python?
I have an add-on which uses the "Add Mesh Extra Objects" add-on to function.
Before Blender 4.2, I was using these lines to enable it:
import addon_utils
addon_utils.enable("add_mesh_extra_objects")

However with Blender 4.2 this doesn't work anymore, I believe because they're now extensions?
So is there any way to, through code, enable "Add Mesh Extra Objects" or does the user have to manually enable it now?
I understand it's not hard to enable it manually, however I want the process of using the add-on be as streamlined as possible for the user.
EDIT:
What I've realized since posting is that "add_mesh_extra_objects" and every other add-on that came installed with Blender before Blender 4.2 aren't in the Blender files anymore, and they instead have to be downloaded and then enabled either through the new "Get Extensions" tab in "Preferences..." or from a website.
So just using addon_utils.enable("add_mesh_extra_objects") won't work unless the add-on is downloaded and placed in the new "addons_core" folder in C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.2\4.2\scripts.
I'm kind of hoping that I'm just missing something, maybe it's just a new line of code and it's an easy fix but so far I haven't been able to find any way to download and enable the add-on though Python, and the only solution I have so far is to use webbrowser.open("website") to open the download site for the add-on and let the user manually download it.
This really isn't what I want though.
I've tried fiddling around with urllib.request.urlretrieve to try and download the file but I'm being blocked by HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.
This isn't something I'm too familiar with so I'm a bit out of my depths.

I was able to solve my issue.
First, get the users blender addon folder so it doesn't matter what operator system the user has, then download the addon zip, extract the zip and then enable the addon.
import bpy
import requests
import os
import zipfile

# Add-on module name
addon_folder_name = "add_mesh_extra_objects"

# Get the user Blender scripts directory
user_scripts_path = bpy.utils.script_path_user()
addons_path = os.path.join(user_scripts_path, "addons")
addon_path = os.path.join(addons_path, addon_folder_name)

# URL for the add-on download
addon_url = "https://extensions.blender.org/download/sha256:c0708c26e4d7a5fd9f3dd6dadc86288f2270c338ba1c984ba0f37e6098f7756d/add-on-extra-mesh-objects-v0.3.12.zip?repository=%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fextensions%2F&blender_version_min=4.2.0"

# Function to download and install the add-on
def download_and_install_addon():
    if not os.path.exists(addon_path):
        # Ensure the addons directory exists
        if not os.path.exists(addons_path):
            os.makedirs(addons_path)

        # Define the file name and full path
        filename = "addon_extra_mesh_objects.zip"
        file_path = os.path.join(addons_path, filename)

        # Download the zip file
        response = requests.get(addon_url)
        with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(response.content)

        # Extract the zip file
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(addon_path)

    # Refresh script paths and enable the add-on
    bpy.utils.refresh_script_paths()
    bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module=addon_folder_name)
    bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()

# Run the function to install and enable the add-on
download_and_install_addon()

